# Scala NodeSeq reduce/foldLeft with newlines

Tags: scala, newline, reduce, xmlnode

Assume this is pretty easy but having a hard time printing out NodeSeq of html tags with newlines (so when I view source in web browser, I can scan top-to-bottom)

As is, the NodeSeq is printed as one long line.

example code:

```
listOfPaths map ( jsNode(_) ) reduce (_++_)

def jsNode(path: String): NodeSeq =
  <script type="text/javascript" src={"/static/js/"+path}></script>
```

So, how to get a *\n* at end of each node?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a job for whatever you're using to render the HTML. For example, if you're using [scala.xml.PrettyPrinter](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/PrettyPrinter.html), you could do something like this:

```
val printer = new xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
val paths = List("script-1.js", "script-2.js")
val header = <head>{paths map ( jsNode(_) ) reduce (_++_)}</head>
```

Now when you call `printer.format(header)`, you'll get the following:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script-1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script-2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note that the first argument to the `PrettyPrinter` constructor specifies the page width, and the second the number of spaces to indent.

If you just want something quick and dirty, you could drop a text node between (or after) the elements:

```
paths map ( jsNode(_) ) reduce (_++ Text("\n") ++ _)
```

But the other solution is almost always preferable.

Comment: thanks, the latter, quick & dirty, does the trick for right now: just want to quickly visually parse the output, in production google mod_pagespeed will compress the entire source html into 1 long unreadable line anyway ;-)